# Choosing carefully the collation of a SQL Server 2008 engine

Tags: sql-server, collation, case-sensitive

I've been asking myself this question for a while now and cannot find any good advice on the web. We're running database servers with `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

We're developping applications that can be translated into **french, german, italian and english**.

Now, if I would like to create a new database from scratch, what would be the best collation in that case ?

I've found documentation on this subject, I know it will change our way of sorting and comparing stuff in our databases but I haven't found any good sources to help us choosing the correct one !

We'be been using `FRENCH_CI_AS` for a while now, but we do miss a little bit the case sentivity... What would be the best choice for us ?

I've read that many companies use `LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS`, but still no case sensitivity, and I really don't get why they don't take case sensitivity, especially when dealing with languages such as german, which requires case sensitivity ! Are there drawbacks in choosing CS collations ? If so, what are they ?

Edit :
What is the best collation to use (in our case) ?

- `LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS`
- `LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS`
- `FRENCH_CI_AS`
- `FRENCH_CS_AS`
- Another collation that would fit better our languages prerequisities ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the collation on

- database level
- column level, and
- statement/operation level (comparison, order-by)

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx))

For example, you can define a NVARCHAR column case-insensitive (for search), but apply a case-sensitive collation in the ORDER BY clause of a SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in order to start a new database based on a good basis, what would be the best collation to choose for our database engine !